# conda can't update itself

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm on linux machine with rhel7 and when I tried to install some packages, I got the following message.

```
Solving environment: failed

CondaValueError: Malformed version string '~': invalid character(s).
```

Google search suggested to update conda (my conda version is 4.5.11). So I tried to update conda, but canda failed to update although no errors, as shown below.

```
$ conda update -n base conda
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
current version: 4.5.11
latest version: 4.8.3

Please update conda by running

$ conda update -n base conda

# All requested packages already installed.

$ conda --version
conda 4.5.11
```

Repeating the command got the same result.

Comment: that doesn't seem to have worked properly, I'd try `conda install -n base conda=4.8.3`

Comment: @cel thanks! it worked, though it failed initially due to not finding python3.8 and i had to get python3.8 in an unusual way (my env has python3.5).

Comment: That makes sense! python3.5 is close to EOL and is not widely supported anymore in the conda packaging community. I added an answer for other people who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your version of python-3.5 is not supported anymore by the official channels and thus conda could not find a suitable package to update.

You can explicitly request an update by running:

```
conda install -n base conda=4.8.3 python=3.8
```

Comment: Thanks.   I think conda should show a more informative message for situation like this. The message I got is not only non-informative, but also misleading.

Comment: Almost always when you get this "loop" update issue in CONDA, is because you have a package that is dependent on a older version of PYTHON.

Comment: How can I tell which package is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Well, I met this problem because I didn't execute the `conda update conda` on the Powershell of base(root) environment, and instead, I executed it on the Powershell of MiniConda3 (or other) environments.

So, if you have installed Anaconda Navigator, I suggest you launch the Powershell Prompt inside the base(root) environment, and type
`conda update conda` on it...
[image]

It's a shame for me to say this out, but it did work for me immediately ,and I hope this will help.